# Prove that 5 is a limit point of the closed interval [2,5]

Tags: analysis

This is for a math analysis class.

Prove that $5 $ is a limit point of the closed interval $[2,5] $

Comment: Can you find a sequence in $[2, \, 5]$ whose limit is  $5$?

Comment: @Paul Just use the sequence $5-\frac{1}{n}$ to show that $5$ is the limit of a sequence with entries in the desired interval.

Comment: It would be much better if you show us your progress and where did you encounter a problem.

Comment: 5 - 1/n? confused what you mean.

Comment: This is what I have. Proof: Let (a,b) be an open interval, Then a < 2 < b. So case 1: Assume 5 < or equal to 5 then there is a point r such that 2 < r < b < 5 so r is an element of [2,5]. Case 2: Assume b > 5. Observe that 4.5 is an element of M for some M. 4.5 is an element in (1,b) and 4.5 is not equal to 2. So in either case this works. However, I know i obviously have flaws.

Comment: @Paul Let $n$ run over the positive integers. Then $5-\frac{1}{n}$ is strictly increasing , starting with $4$ and converging to $5$

Comment: @Paul You really need to think again about your argument. Why would you assume $5<5$? Also, $2 \not \in (a,b)$ for $a,b$ arbitrary.

Comment: @paul first, welcome to the community.  You will get a much better response around here if you include any thoughts or work you have attempted at the time of post.  What work you show should be added to the original post rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> **Definition:**
>   Let $S$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. A point $x\in X$ is called a limit point if every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $S$ different from $X$.

We need to check if $x=5$ satisfies this condition for $X=\mathbb R$ and $S=[2,5]$.

Since the open intervalls are a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ it suffices to check this condition for open intervals. So let $I\subset \mathbb R$ be a Intervall containing $5$, i.e. $I=(5-\epsilon_1, 5+\epsilon_2)$ for arbitrary $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 >0$. Can you find an $y\in S$, $y\ne x$ which only depends on $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$?

Hint: You can either explicitely write down $y$ or give an algorithmus for calculating it.

---

In first countable spaces, (like metric spaces and this example), the definition of a limit point is equivalent to something else. What is it?